# C# - How to execute async methods in batch?

Tags: c#, api, rest

I have C# SDK for REST API that was written some time ago. The API creators added new endpoint that allows to call multiple actions with single HTTP request. At this moment my SDK looks like this:

```cs
interface ISubApi<T> where T : IResponseModel
{
    public Task<IResponse<T>> FindAllAsync(int offset = 0, int limit = 1000, IDictionary<string, string> @params = default);
    public Task<IResponse<T>> FindOneAsync(IDictionary<string, string> @params = default);
    public Task<IResponse<T>> UpsertOneAsync(object input);
}

class OtherCustomApi : ISubApi<OtherCustomModel>
{
    public async Task<IResponse<OtherCustomModel>> FindAllAsync(int offset = 0, int limit = 1000, IDictionary<string, string> @params = null)
    {
       ...
    }

    public async Task<IResponse<OtherCustomModel>> FindOneAsync(IDictionary<string, string> @params = null)
    {
       ...
    }

    public async Task<IResponse<OtherCustomModel>> UpsertOneAsync(object input)
    {
       ...
    }
}

class CustomApi : ISubApi<CustomModel>
{
    public async Task<IResponse<CustomModel>> FindAllAsync(int offset = 0, int limit = 1000, IDictionary<string, string> @params = null)
    {
       ...
    }

    public async Task<IResponse<CustomModel>> FindOneAsync(IDictionary<string, string> @params = null)
    {
       ...
    }

    public async Task<IResponse<CustomModel>> UpsertOneAsync(object input)
    {
       ...
    }
}

class Manager
{
    public ISubApi<CustomModel> CustomApi { get; private set; }
    public ISubApi<OtherCustomModel> OtherCustomApi { get; private set; }

    public Manager()
    {
        CustomApi = new CustomApi();
        OtherCustomApi = new OtherCustomApi();
    }
}

Manager manager = new();

await manager.CustomApi.UpsertOneAsync(new { });
await manager.OtherCustomApi.UpsertOneAsync(new { });
```

I would like to implement ability to call batch endpoint like that:

```
await manager.Batch.ExecuteAsync(
    manager.CustomApi.UpsertOneAsync(new { });
    manager.OtherCustomApi.UpsertOneAsync(new { });
)
```

Under the hood it should get from every method endpoint, body and params, join them together and send to the batch API endpoint.

Is it possible with C#? If not, how it should be done correctly?

Comment: You can make `ExecuteAsync` accept `params Expression<Func<Manager, Task>> exprs` and call it like `ExecuteAsync(m => m.CustomApi.UpsertOneAsync(...), m => m.OtherCustomApi.UpsertOneAsync(...))` and then analyze the passed expressions but I would argue that this is not worth the time.

Comment: @GuruStron So, what to you suggest? Reworking all the design?

Comment: Yes, I would just created a specific method with specific contract which mimics the batch endpoint following the KISS principle. But without seeing the whole code it is hard to say.